# vb.net listbox, grabbing a particular item from each selectedindex until there are none left

Tags: vb.net, listbox, selectedindex

Having a really hard time figuring this one out, google is not helping.

I have a list box that is populated with 3 columns and however many rows/SelectedIndex's as is needed from previous steps in the program.

Now I am trying to print the results to a printout, but I only need what is in one of those columns in the printout (this is a different sub routine by the way.) and I need it from each SelectedIndex until there are none left, no idea how to get this to work properly, no idea what to Loop.

Any help would pre appreciated, if you need more details just ask.

Comment: need more details, like code showing what you have tried

Comment: Figured it out on my own, thanks anyway though!

Answer (score 0):

Aaaaaand I am dumb, Answered my own question by just thinking about it a bit more.

Used a form level Counter that was incremented each time a new item was added to the listbox, and just used that in a loop to grab the specific item from each column until there were none left.

Comment: Perhaps you should post your code to explain your ideas properly. Listbox does not support columns in its traditional sense (I was precisely writing an answer explaining that).

Comment: I got the individual variable from each line, or selectedindex of the listbox by using a trim/substring , do what I want with it, and then the loop proceeds to the next line out of howevermany until it runs out.

Comment: OK. But this is not a proper column/row distinction as in ListView or in DataGridView. The whole point of my answer was highlighting that; if you were just worried about getting the given item, this is a different story... Perhaps you should update your question/answer with your code (problem+solution) or just delete everything as far as it is not too clear what has happened here (where the problem was and what the solution was about) :)